# How to disable import logging from Pyinstaller executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

How can I disable all the import logging that is fired off when running the executable compiled by Pyinstaller?

This is my set up:

```
a = Analysis(["model_trainer.py"],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=BINARIES,
             datas=DATA_FILES,
             hiddenimports=HIDDEN_IMPORTS,
             cipher=BLOCK_CIPHER,
             noarchive=True)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=BLOCK_CIPHER)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [("v", None, "OPTION")],
          name=name,
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False)

coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name=name)
```

These are the logs when I run my executable with `/project/model_trainer/` from terminal... how can I disable these? I was under the impression that `debug=False` and `console=False` would disable these.

```
root@desktop:/# /project/model_trainer
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import sys # builtin
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to silence these import workings changing

`[("v", None, "OPTION")],`

to

`[("W ignore", None, "OPTION")],`

I.e. from verbose run-time to warning ignore.